# Comparing two regression models with python

Tags: python, regression

How to compare two regression models using python. In R , able to compare using anova(md1,md2). But in python tried to use sm.stats.anova_lm(md1,md2) is show AttributeError: 'MixedLMResults' object has no attribute 'ssr'

R example:
`md1 = lmer(A ~ B + (1|Z), data = df, REML = FALSE)`
`md2 = lmer(A ~ B + C + (1|Z), data = df, REML = FALSE)`
`anova(md1,md2)`

python example:
`md1= smf.mixedlm("A ~ B", data=df ,groups=df["Z"]).fit(reml=False)`
`md2= smf.mixedlm("A ~ B + C", data=df ,groups=df["Z"]).fit(reml=False)`
`result = sm.stats.anova_lm(md1,md2)`

RMSE and R-square:
`md= smf.mixedlm("A ~ B", data=df ,groups=df["Z"]).fit(reml=False)`

`y= df["A"]`
`y_predict = md.fittedvalues`
`RMSE = np.sqrt((( y - y_predict)**2).values.mean())`
 `Rsquared = 1.0 - (np.var( y - y_predict) / np.var(y))`

`print("\n")`
`print("RMSE: ", RMSE)`
 `print("R-squared: ", Rsquared)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to use RMSE and R-squared for the comparison, here is example code to calculate those values. This code snippet assumes that the fitted parameters from the regressions are named "fittedParameters", the dependent data is named "yData", the independent data is named "xData", and the ffitted function is named "func":

```
import numpy

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

error = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(error) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(error) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```

Comment: @James_Phillips.Thank. I tried your answer the RMSE and R -squared. uncertain if I put the code the right way. Pls find above the example. Many thanks